# Apache error: htaccess without matching section

Tags: apache, compiler-errors

I'm getting this message in my Apache error console:

> [Thu Jun 27 11:56:07 2013] [alert] [client 127.0.0.1]  /Users/.......htacces  without matching  section

It started after my MAMP server wouldnt start and i found some online info that suggested entering `ps aux/ grep mysql lsof _-i Killall -9 mysqld` when this failed, I tried 2nd suggestion `sudo Killall -9 mysqld`. This came up with a warning so i called it. I then recalled that i had the same problem before and simple quit mysqld in my activity monitor, and the MAMP server worked again. I tried that, the server worked but got I then got a error message saying:

> 500 internal server error  The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator, you@example.com and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

I checked Apache error console and got this:

> [Thu Jun 27 11:56:07 2013] [alert] [client 127.0.0.1]  /Users/.......htacces  without matching  section

Comment: Did you look in the .htaccess file that apache is complaining about ?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I cant find the .htaccess file.

Comment: Located .htaccass file. Is as follows:

# END WordPress
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /macoco1/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /macoco1/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress